# Open XML and display data in div

Tags: javascript, xml

I am new to xml and found this example that I load in a directory on my computer.

XML file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <!--  Edited by XMLSpy® 
  --> 
- <CATALOG>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1982</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Eros</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>One night only</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1998</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.10</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1973</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.50</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1999</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1971</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Stop</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1991</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Red</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>London</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
  </CATALOG>
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

function displayCD(i)
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br />Title: " + title + "<br />Year: "+ year;
document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD(2)">

<div id='showCD'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

An error turns up in the browser saying that "x" is undefined.  Are there specific settings needed for this simple example to work?

Comment: Probably `xtmlDoc` is empty, have you tried to see what is in `xmlhttp.responseXML`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml file format was the problem.  I found out when I looked for a different demo that worked.

This HTML worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

function displayCD(i)
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br />Title: " + title + "<br />Year: "+ year;
document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD(5)">

<div id='showCD'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

With this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<CATALOG>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1982</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Eros</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>One night only</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1998</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.10</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1973</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.50</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1999</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1971</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Stop</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1991</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Red</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>London</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
  </CATALOG>
```

Thanks again for working so much on this.

Answer (score 1):

"(...) load in a directory on my computer"
It's the problem. It's default impossible due to security reasons. You should do it on a server (it can be local server).

Some browsers permit it but you have to change configuration (e.g. in Opera `opera:config#UserPrefs|AllowFileXMLHttpRequest`).

Edit.

I checked. After setting in Opera `Allow File XMLHttpRequest` everything works well.
In Firefox 5.0 it works by default for me.

Edit2.

I found the solution! :)

Your code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
xmlhttp = "";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://"+location.host+"/cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

function displayCD(i)
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br />Title: " + title + "<br />Year: "+ year;
document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD(2)">

<div id='showCD'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

1. Read my original answer.
2. Read my comment: I don't know why but in this case you need to pass absolute path (not relative) to make this script working in IE.
3. You need to put this line `xmlhttp = "";` in the beginning to make it working in IE.

That's all. :)

Comment: There was also an error for `xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);` The error was "Access denied". How do I allow xmlhttp requests?  The xml file is in that same directory.

Comment: Do you use IE? Try this: `xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); if(!xmlhttp) {//code for other browsers}`

Comment: When comes to filesystem's rights, only thing you need is possibility to read xml file. Maybe you have to change some settings in IE but if so, I can't help.

Comment: On the server it will works well for 100%. Just install a local server and problem will be gone... E.g. VertigoServ is easy to install.

Comment: `xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` returns a `null or undefined object`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help. :( I tried to run this on IE 9 and I got the same error. I tried to search but I can't find any working solution. It works on Firefox, Google Chrome and Opera but doesn't work on IE. Sorry, I don't know why. :|

Comment: Wait, I have something. For IE you have to pass absolute path, not relative. So change `xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);` to `xmlhttp.open("GET","http://"+location.host+"cd_catalog.xml",false);` or something like this. Now you shouldn't get "Access denied" error. But still I don't know why getElementsByTagName doesn't work. :|

Comment: I found the solution. :) Read my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the work you did on this. The problem seems to be in my web server settings or my IE settings.

Comment: Still get an error...? What error? I can try to help you. :) When comes to IE settings, you can try visit your site using this: http://www.ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ There are default setting for IE.

Comment: The problem is that the `xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` doesn't create the object. This must be a security issue with the IIS web server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what may be the problem. I don't use IIS. You can create a new question, maybe someone will help you...

Comment: I found the problem!  The xml file format was not standard.  Thanks again for everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Ignore my answer, I didn't notice that you set async to false.**

Your problem is that you're trying to do something with the data before you actually receive it. You have to use the `onreadystatechange` event to capture the status and data. I'm just going to quote from MDN because they do a much better job of actually explaining it:

> [...] you need to decide what you want to do after you receive the server response to your request. At this stage, you just need to tell the HTTP request object which JavaScript function will handle processing the response. This is done by setting the onreadystatechange property of the object to the name of the JavaScript function that should be called when the state of the request changes [...]

They have a handy guide located here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started