# Difference in security handling between HTML http request and XML http request

Tags: security, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

What are the differences between an HTML http request and an XML http request. I get an access denied error for this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
```

The xml file is in the same directory as the html file where that request is made.

Comment: Have you ruled out a problem on your server?  I.e. do you get a 500 when you `curl` the XML but get a 200 when you `curl` the HTML?

Comment: It refers to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004633/open-xml-and-display-data-in-div

Comment: IE shows a blank page with an error message indicator.  When I look at the error message it says access denied.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in how `XMLHttpRequest` deals with XML vs HTML vs any other content-type of request.

If your server is not serving the XML at all you will see access denied.

If your server is redirecting `*.xml` requests to a different virtual domain or protocol, then you will see access denied because the redirect is cross-origin.

If your XML contains an [external entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-external-ent) that is cross-domain, then that might cause problems as well.

Comment: Are there specific settings needed for the server to allow xml?

Comment: @user823527, Without knowing anything about your server, it's impossible to say.