# Is there any way to show Raw XML data in Popup without default alert box?

Tags: jquery, xml, modal-dialog, alert, bootbox

I want to show raw XML data with tags in Popups like Bootstrap Modal, BootBox, jAlert, SweetAlert2, or SweetAlert.
But when I feed the raw XML data, those libraries only show the content inside the tags.
I want something like

```
<Account>
    <Name>Customer Name</Name>
    <Balance>Current Balance</Balance>
</Account>
```

But those libraries show only

```
Customer Name
Current Balance
```

Only the default alert dialog box shows the content with XML tags.
I was trying to fix this issue by replacing using jQuery

```
< with &lt; and > with &gt;
```

But my team lead says not to change any data by any means.
Is there any plugin or any way to show raw XML with a beautiful alert box?

Comment: Append the XML content in to `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: I already tried. Not working :)

Comment: It should. If you can edit the question to show your code, then we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question asked in your title,

> Is there any way to show Raw XML data in Popup with default alert box?

Yes, the default JavaScript `alert()`,

```
alert(`<Account>
    <Name>Customer Name</Name>
    <Balance>Current Balance</Balance>
</Account>`)
```

will show raw XML data:

[image]

### See also

- [Show XML via ACE code editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51349224/290085)

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. 
I made a mistake while asking the question, the question should be like this
''Is there any way to show Raw XML data in Popup without default alert box?"

Comment: You can also open a new window or float a simulated modal `div` containing XML in an ACE editor (see included link) or any other HTML/CSS including a simple `<pre></pre>` wrapper.

Comment: How you meet the modal requirement will vary per your framework (or whether you're creating the modal alert yourself using custom HTML/CSS), but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7519618/290085) for more options on the XML display part.

Comment: Thank you. I finally solve this issue by using textarea in bootbox.