# xml not retrived by javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

This may seem too trivial but I have tried all possible methods

1. async=true  (onreadystatechange)
2. async=false  (xmlhttp open)

source http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_httprequest.asp

3.xmlhttp.open("GET","http://"+location.host+"/cd_catalog.xml",false)

source

[Open XML and display data in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004633/open-xml-and-display-data-in-div)

basically what I want is for javascript and xml in the same folder and use javascript to return values.

The actual program I am working on:

```
var xmlSolver = function MakeXmlSolver(){};
xmlSolver.GetAllAuthorsInStock()=function()
{
var author=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName   
    ("author").childNodes.nodeValue;

return author;
 };

   xmlSolver.GetAllBooksInStock()=function()
   {
var title=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName
     ("title").childNodes.nodeValue;
     }
```

and the xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database -->
<bookCollection>
  <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
    <title>The Gorgias</title>
    <author>
      <name>Plato</name>
    </author>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <firstName>Benjamin</firstName>
      <lastName>Franklin</lastName>
    </author>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <firstName>Herman</firstName>
      <lastName>Melville</lastName>
    </author>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="2002" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
    <title>Oryx and Crake</title>
    <author>
      <firstName>Margaret</firstName>
      <lastName>Atwood</lastName>
    </author>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
    <title>The Republic</title>
    <author>
      <name>Plato</name>
    </author>
    <price>7.99</price>
  </book>
</bookCollection>
```

Comment: and what problem are you having...?  (are you seeing an error in the console? and if so, what does the error say?)

Comment: I am unable to get 'authors' and 'title' from xml,, probably the xml is not loaded by xmlhttp...

Comment: have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @sfletche  Access is denied

Comment: I tested on both IE and chrome latest versions

Comment: Sounds like a [CORS issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).  One possible workaround (for Chrome at least) is to install the [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) plugin.

Comment: @sfletche  nope doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [CORS issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to me. This is basically a safety mechanism built into browsers that prevents the javascript from reading your local files.

One possible workaround (for the Chrome browser at least) is to install and enable the [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en).